# How to make a rope with SpriteKit's SKPhysicsJointLimit?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am using a for loop to make 7 rope link sprites, can't figure out how to make rope out of them with SKPhysicsJointLimit. :'(

```
-(void)ropeStuff {
    int i ;
    int y;
    SKSpriteNode *ropes;
    SKPhysicsJointLimit * ropeLink;
    NSMutableArray *ropeArray;

    for (i = 0 ; i < 7; ++i) {

        if (i) {
            int x = 16;
            y = (x * i);
            ropes.position = CGPointMake(_cat.position.x, _cat.position.y + (x * i) );
        }
        ropes = [SKSpriteNode node];
        ropes = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"rope link.png"];
        ropes.position = CGPointMake(_cat.position.x, _cat.position.y +5);
        ropes.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:1];
        ropes.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
        ropes.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
        ropes.name = @"rope";

        [_worldNode addChild:ropes];
        if (i) {
            ropeLink = [SKPhysicsJointLimit jointWithBodyA:ropes.physicsBody          
            bodyB:ropes.physicsBody anchorA:ropes.position anchorB:ropes.position];
            [_worldNode.scene.physicsWorld addJoint:ropeLink];
        }
    }
    }
```

Thank you all for the help! :D

Comment: You are joining the same nodes (ropes with ropes). You need to save the previous node and connect the previous and the current nodes. BTW, you should set the maxmiumLength property of ropeLink.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using SKPhysicsJointLimit? The rope is a group of segments that rotate relatively each other. You should use SKPhysicsJointPin with or without rotation limits.

Comment: But if you use SKPhysicsJointPin, the rope will have "elasticity" behaviour to it. Which doesn't simulate a rope very well at all.